# Wallet Adapter - WalletNotSelectedError while trying to connect wallet to dApp

Tags: react, solana-wallet-adapter

I'm trying to connect the user wallet to my dApp programmatically. That is, I created my own "connect wallet" button and when clicked it should execute the `connect` function that `wallet-adapter` exposes through its React Context.

```
import { clusterApiUrl } from '@solana/web3.js'
import { useWallet } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react'
import { WalletAdapterNetwork } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-base'
import { PhantomWalletAdapter } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets'
import {
  ConnectionProvider,
  WalletProvider
} from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react'

const Button = () => {
    const { connect } = useWallet()

    return (
        <button onClick={connect}>
          Connect wallet
        </button>
    )
}

const App = () => {
    return (
        <ConnectionProvider endpoint={clusterApiUrl(WalletAdapterNetwork.Devnet)}>
            <WalletProvider wallets={[new PhantomWalletAdapter()]}>
                <Button />
            </WalletProvider>
        </ConnectionProvider>
    )

}
```

But this approach throws the error that is in the title. At this point I'm wondering if it's possible to use `wallet-adapter` without using its components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`connect()` name could be misleading. This function *connects* to an adapter that the user has already chosen and authenticated with. `WalletProvider` only declares the supported adapters.

Before you can `connect()`, you need to `select()` the wallet you want to use.

```
import { PhantomWalletName } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-phantom";
const { select } = useWallet();
select(PhantomWalletName);
```

Comment: I also would add that TypeScript will raise an error if you pass a string to the `select` function. I had to import `PhantomWalletName` from `@solana/wallet-adapter-phantom` and pass it to the `select` function to resolve this error.

Comment: Good call! I've updated the answer.